# Can't SSH Into EC2 Instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

So I spun my instance up from the web, downloaded a keypair installed it and everything worked great for about a day. Then I rebooted my computer, and I'm not able to SSH into it anymore. I tried redownloading a keypair and reinstalling it but I keep getting the Permission denied (publickey) error.

This is the verbose output (I've tried using the -i /path/to/keypair option as well with no luck):

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-184-73-218-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com [184.73.218.40] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tigger/.ec2/domainpolish type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/tigger/.ec2/domainpolish-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-184-73-218-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tigger/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tigger/.ec2/domainpolish
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: domainpolish
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've also tried rebooting the instance. Anyone have anything else I can try? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd post the same on the Amazon forum for this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30

There's a trick that AWS employees have that most SO users do not: they can see what's going on.  :)

Comment: & then if you get the answer, please report back on the answer section it might be of good help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I had deleted my AWS keypair from my computer. Don't do this. It will lock you out of your instance forever.