# Can't get into my EC2 instance using SSH, problem with publickey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Hope this is the right place to ask for this, but I have tried several troubleshootings, and I have no idea what seems to be the problem.

I need to SSH into my EC2 instance, and I have my pem key in downloads, so as usual I would go:

```
cd Downloads
```

followed by

```
ssh -i "PMARQUET.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

which was what had always worked, and I get the following message:

```
ec2-user@ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I already had done the chmod 400 for the pem file,so it is not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193768/trying-to-ssh-into-an-amazon-ec2-instance-permission-error) and I made sure it was the **PMARQUET** key pair.

The file is there since I runned:

```
test -f "Downoads/PMARQUET.pem"; echo "it exists"
```

and I got:

```
it exists
```

so it is not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120589/cant-ssh-into-ec2-instance) problem

Also it is the key, as you can see:

[image]

Following some more trouble shooting I tried to get a more verbose message:

```
ssh -vvv -i "PMARQUET.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

which spitted out:

```
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
    debug2: resolving "ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [18.216.174.33] port 22. 
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file PMARQUET.pem type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file PMARQUET.pem-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    debug3: send packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: receive packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal  
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KzQVpFJkDKl/E7/wsbu2O95w29ul3J+vi6DG02dXNh0
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 18.216.174.33
    debug1: Host 'ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/derek/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug2: key: PMARQUET.pem ((nil)), explicit
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 7
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
    debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: PMARQUET.pem
    debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:HxigzE3i74MQ+amoQ/3Ke7g8PqmRsbvhIX6PJGdnZjc
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    ec2-user@ec2-18-216-174-33.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

It still seems as if there is a public key problem, but I don't know what it could be, the file is most surely there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would move the file into the `~/.ssh` folder, because the folder permissions are also important. You can also reference the file using `ssh -i ~/.ssh/PMARQUET.pem ...` without having to cd to that folder

Comment: Might be worth double-checking the fingerprint for PMARQUET.pem matches the configured PMARQUET key pair in EC2. See https://serverfault.com/questions/603982/why-does-my-openssh-key-fingerprint-not-match-the-aws-ec2-console-keypair-finger for how to do this.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide//TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingSSH

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right EC2 instance? If an Amazon EC2 instance is stopped and started, it will receive a different Public IP address. So, the address might have changed since you last used it.

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein, I am sure is the right one

Comment: Well, it's saying that the `PMARQUET.pem` file you provided does not contain a private key that matches a public key stored in the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on that target server. (_Why_ that is the case, we do not know.) To regain access, you could try to [Connect Using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) or use [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with.html) (depending on which AMI you are using).